# Always printing in landscape format

Tags: printing, landscape

I am using latest Greenshot - a great tool!

One question:
My printer normally prints in portrait format
But: I would like to force Greenshot to always use landscape format.
I tried several settings without finding  solution for all snapshots.

Do you have a hint allowing me to print **all** screenshots - independent from snapshot size - in landscape?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the OS, and Greenshot is for Mac *and* PC. For a Windows OS, you can either set a *physical* printer to default to landscape, or use indirection, and set a *virtual* printer, such as *Microsoft Print to PDF*, to landscape. This does require creating an intermediate PDF document, but if printing many documents, you can send all PDF's to the printer at once, so it's only one extra step total for any number of documents.

[image: Set Print PDF to Landsacpe]